# Storyboard doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'goToC'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard, segue

I want to enter the CameraViewController by clicking a button and then take a picture of qr code.
I keep getting this error
Thank U all for the help
I gave every ViewController it's type in the Storyboard

```
import UIKit

class movieListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var movieTableView: UITableView!



    var movie:[Movie] = [Movie]()
    var currentMovies:[Movie] = [Movie]()
    var counter = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        movie = Helpers.downloadJson()
        self.movieTableView.reloadData()
        sort()

    }

    func sort() {
        movie.sort(by: { $0.releaseYear < $1.releaseYear })
        movieTableView.reloadData()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return movie.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MovieCell") as! MovieCell

        cell.createCell(movie: movie[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedMovie = movie[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDetail", sender: selectedMovie)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let nextVC = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
        nextVC.movie = sender as! Movie
    }

    @IBAction func addTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let nextView = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "goToC") as! CameraViewController
        self.present(nextView, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}

    CameraViewController:


    import UIKit
    import AVFoundation

    class CameraViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

        var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
        var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
        var qrCodeFrameView: UIView?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

            do {
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
                captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
                captureSession?.addInput(input)
            } catch {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            let captureMetaDataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetaDataOutput)
            captureMetaDataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            captureMetaDataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]
            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
            view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

            captureSession?.startRunning()

            qrCodeFrameView = UIView()

            if let newFrame = qrCodeFrameView {
                newFrame.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
                newFrame.layer.borderWidth = 2
                view.addSubview(newFrame)
                view.bringSubview(toFront: newFrame)
            }

        }

    }




    DetailViewController

    import UIKit

    class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet weak var movieImage: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var titleLbl: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var releaseYearLbl: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var ratingLbl: UILabel!

        var movie: Movie = Movie()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            titleLbl.text = movie.title
            ratingLbl.text = "Rating: \(movie.rating) ⭐️"
            releaseYearLbl.text = "Release Year: \(movie.releaseYear)"

            movieImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
            movieImage.clipsToBounds = true

            movieImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: movie.image))
        }

        @IBAction func backToList(_ sender: Any) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


    }
```

Comment: You must have did setting segue wrongly...

Comment: Check the segue that they are proper and it the destination view controller is the same as you want it to be

Comment: possible duplicate [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440964/cant-cast-value-of-type-uiviewcontroller-to-patterndetailviewcontroller)

Comment: do you have any other segues initiating from movielist view controller ?

Comment: Specifically check the segue going from `movieListViewController` to `DetailViewController`. I guess you by mistakenly made segue between `movieListViewController` to `CamerViewController`.

Comment: And if you have two segues from single Viewcontroller then do a check of identifier before typecasting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Xcode 8.2.1**

I thought `CameraViewController` is in your `Main` storyboard.

In `Main` story board first select yellow button top of the appropriate `viewController` and goto `identity inspector -> identity -> Storyboard ID` enter your view controller identifier for this case `goToC`

[image]